# Parse YAML using shell

Tags: parsing, yaml, yq

I have a yaml something of this sort and need to parse and get the value of 'url' here.

```
name: Yaml_Test
servers:
- name: host_ip
  host: host_name
  port: 443
  scheme: https

variables:
- constant:
    name: url
    value: https://url_here
```

Answer (score 0):

With the current versions of both [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) and [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), use `select` to filter the array items:

```
.variables[].constant | select(.name == "url").value
```

```
https://url_here
```

Using [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you may want to add the `-r` option to output raw text:

```sh
yq -r '…' file.yaml
```

Using an older version of [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq), you need to specify the command `e` or `eval`:

```sh
yq e '…' file.yaml
```

---

Edit: Although not recommended, here's as requested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601351/parse-yaml-using-shell/71601787?noredirect=1#comment126547274_71601787) a `grep`-only solution which heavily relies on how the YAML document is represented textually, based on the sample provided (i.e. no other occurrence of `name: url` etc.):

```sh
grep -A1 'name: url' file.yaml | grep -o 'http.*'
```

```
https://url_here
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I should have explicitly specified this, Sorry. I need to do without using any external tools like yq and using only shell native commands like sed, awk, grep or even jq is fine. The only intention here is to avoid using 'pip' to install yq due to some restrictions.

Comment: @Sillekyatha You explicitly tagged your question with `yq`, and (either implementation of) `yq` is a very good choice to handle YAML data. In general, when dealing with structured data such as YAML you should avoid using tools like `awk` or `sed` because they only operate (and thus rely) on specific textual representations, not the actual (logical) structure of the document's format. Also, with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) you basically use `jq` under the hood, as it is just a YAML wrapper for `jq` (converting to and from JSON). `jq` by itself cannot interpret YAML, only JSON.

Comment: I understand that yq uses jq under the hood and completely agree that yq is the apt tool to parse yaml instead of sed or awk but I'm badly in a condition where I'm not supposed to touch python or install anything using pip.

Comment: @Sillekyatha I have added a `grep`-only solution, but use it at your own risk as any modifications to the YAML data may lead to unwanted results.